# How to write this json data as an associative array in php?

Tags: php, json, associative-array

**DETAILS**

I am getting the following json data back via an ajax response.

```
"result":[{"word":"jquery","wordID":"1"},{"word":"github","wordID":"2"}]
```

I am trying to understand the information I've received (arrays confuse me). To do that I am trying to recreate the structure of the array in php.

If I were to recreate the array above would I write it like this?

```
$result=Array (
    [0] => Array (
        word => jquery
        wordID => 1        
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        word => github
        wordID => 2 
    )
```

If no, how would I write it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_decode` to convert json in an array , and then do a `var_dump` to see if the structure is what you need

Comment: I've chosen your answer as the answer because it best helped me examine the structure of the data I was trying to understand. Thanks :)

Comment: anytime :) glad that I could help

Answer (score 1):

JSON is essentially the right-hand side of an assignment operation in Javascript, e.g.

```
var foo = [1,2,3];
          ^^^^^^^--- basically json
```

Your snippet above is, however, **NOT** valid json. You've got an object, which cannot simply show up as

```
"key":"value"
```

it has to be

```
{"key":"value"}
```